# "Permissions for service are set to internal but this request was external" for app in same resource group

Tags: azure-api-apps

The Azure API app [documentation](http://azure.microsoft.com/nb-no/documentation/articles/app-service-api-dotnet-add-authentication/#protect-the-api-app) briefly describe three methods of protecting the API app. One of them is the internal accessibility settings: “Internal - Only other API apps or web apps in the same resource group are allowed to call the API app.”

I have create another Azure API app in the same resource group and hosting plan. But a get a HTTP 403 authorization failure with the following error message when I try to connect to the interal API app from the Web App:
“Permissions for service  are set to internal but this request was external.”

Has anyone been able to use the internal settings between API Apps in the same Resource Group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We will be documenting this soon.  in the meantime, what you need to do is the following. You need to install nuget package Microsoft.Azure.AppService.ApiApps.Service. Then, create a delegating handler as follows:

```
class InternalCredentialHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Runtime.FromAppSettings(request).SignHttpRequest(request);
        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Then when you use HttpClient or a generated client to connect to another internal API, simply pass in the delegating handler.  For example:

```
MySampleClient client = new MySampleClient(new DelegatingHandler[] { new InternalCredentialHandler() });
```

Thanks,
Mohit

**Edit**: the documentation for this is now available at https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/app-service-api-dotnet-consume-internal/

Comment: This solved the problem when hosted in Azure. But Runtime.FromAppSettings(request) requires app setting EMA_Secret and EMA_RuntimeUrl to exit in web.config to run on localhost. EMA_Secret can be an empty string, but EMA_RuntimeUrl must be a url for not to crash when FromAppSettings try to convert from string to url with `new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EMA_RuntimeUrl"])`

Comment: The above solution does not work when adding other credentials using Autorest [TokenCredentials](https://github.com/Azure/autorest/blob/master/Microsoft.Rest/ClientRuntime/TokenCredentials.cs): `new MyApi(new TokenCredentials(token), new InternalCredentialHandler())`. My token _"Authorization=Bearer+eyJ0eX..."_ is then replaced with _"Authorization=SharedKey+%3aW..."_, and I'm not able to do authorization in the API. I wan't to use [Thinktecture IdentityServer3](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3) to do additional authorization.

Comment: Hi Tore, could you please explain a little bit why you'd want to use both the platform internal auth and the Thinktecture IdentityServer3 auth at the same time? If you want to use custom auth, would it be sufficient enough to leave your API app as public anonymous?

Comment: I was a bit disappointed when I realized that internal is just authentication. I had expected to get some kind of network protection. I think we instead have to use Cloud Service with IdentityServer to get "true internal" VNET and all authorization possibilities of IdentityServer. We had hoped to have a clean Azure App Services solution. IdentityServer makes it possible for ut to issue tokens that flow with request throug all layers to enable tracking and fine grained authorization at API level.

Comment: I have added an idea for what I want: [http://feedback.azure.com/forums/287595-api-apps/suggestions/7956291-make-api-apps-only-available-internal-on-network-l](http://feedback.azure.com/forums/287595-api-apps/suggestions/7956291-make-api-apps-only-available-internal-on-network-l)

Please vote if you think API Apps should be possible to protect on network level.