# Failed to fetch swagger with error message: Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: json, azure, azure-logic-apps

I have a Function app, which i am calling from a logic App. When ever i am adding the Action for function app, My funciton app unable to retrive. Its showing the below error

> Failed to fetch swagger with error message: Unexpected end of JSON
>   input. Ensure you have CORS enabled on the endpoint and are calling a
>   valid HTTPS endpoint

I have refereed --> [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37717366/azure-logic-apps-error-while-adding-api-apps) , but its not working.

Any help is really appreciated. 
.

Comment: Need urgent help here

Comment: All the you need to do should be go to the Function App, Platform features - > CORS - > and add "*" as a value