# Failed to fetch swagger with error message: Failed to fetch. Ensure you have CORS enabled on the endpoint and are calling a valid HTTPS endpoint

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I'm trying to run a Function from a Logic App. I made the mistake of experimenting with an API definition on a production Function App. I've redeployed the last working commit and restarted the Function app but I still get this error on the Logic Apps side.

How do I get back to where I was?

Comment: check this SO thread - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37717366/azure-logic-apps-error-while-adding-api-apps

Comment: Working but still not in the position I want. I had seen that but missed something in my haste. It was late too. :| Thanks!

Comment: @majita This is actually not the solution... I'd really like to get back to a state where Swagger wasn't involved at all. In other words, before I messed with anything. Now Logic Apps is loading the functions is an unusable way.

Comment: Are you using the "Azure Function" connector or the "HTTP+Swagger" connector when this error shows up?

Comment: Azure Function. You now get a message that starts "For better experience working with Function inputs ... include an API definition ... Learn more" I clicked the link and went through it quickly. No doubt I did something "wrong" but I can't undo what I did.

Answer (score 2):

The way to fix this is to change the CORS settings on your Azure Function to allow all sources with the "*" entry.

See this related [post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/853110c6-b5f5-4713-ad08-dc62960103f5/logic-app-fails-to-fetch-azure-function-swagger?forum=AzureFunctions).

Original CORS Settings
[image]

New CORS Settings
[image]

Comment: I think I should delete this question and start over because I've asked it poorly. That error message is just a symptom of what is happening. Somehow I managed to screw up the API definition and this error was just one of the ways the Function was behaving poorly in Logic Apps. What I ACTUALLY want to know is to do completely undo any changes to the API definition in the Function App and return to an unmodified state.

Comment: Are you able to find the Function in the Logic App designer mode?

Comment: Yes, but I'm given useless endpoints. I now get "Swagger actions" and "Functions". The Swagger actions list is filled with things like /api/$function/delete, /api/$function/get, /api/$function/head. I no longer see a list of the functions themselves. The Functions list now just says "Create new function".

Comment: Did you generate the swagger?

Comment: Yes. That's what I did. After that I started getting the CORS related message but once I fixed that I was in this position I am now.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot or connect with me on Twitter @cajunAA

Comment: Do tou reolve this? what is the logic app url to be added on cors?